# Alternative to dictionary in WCF Service

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, dictionary

I have a WCF webservice, which when the user subscribes (its a WP7 push notification service) it adds a Guid and Uri to the dictionary.
My issue is, when the application stops or restarts the dictionary is obviously emptied.

I would like suggestions for easy and simple alternative ways to store the data whilst minimising memory requirements. This application is running on IIS7 with .net4.

I just need to add to the 'dictionary' and check if it Contains a value. fairly simple really.

Comment: Not always _simplicity_ coincides with _good results_.

Comment: What do you mean "ASP.NET Web Service"? It's a WCF Service. In fact, I don't see what ASP.NET has to do with this question at all.

Comment: Sorry, im getting my terms mixed up.

Comment: I solved this by setting up a SQL Express database to store the values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, in order to keep the data present across server restarts, you obviously need to persist it.

There are two obvious possibilities here:

- Using a database
- Storing the data in a file

I would suggest a database would be the best approach here - it's going to be much simpler to get it to work with multiple WCF servers etc than reading and updating a shared file.

Now you *may* want to keep a cache of results in your server as well, in the form of a dictionary - it depends on what the access tends to look like, whether the data is ever updated (leading to the tricky issue of cache invalidation) and how important your latency requirements are. (If this is a request from a phone, then I suspect the latency of getting the request to your server to start with will dwarf the latency added by a simple database access using an indexed lookup.)

Comment: Thanks Jon, its a simple bit of code, it checks for the phones Guid and if the dictionary does not contain it, it adds the key and value. Then the next method executes the code foreach 'guid'(each phone) in the dictionary. I will pursue the idea of a text file or database as that is what I had in mind. My only concern with the database was memory usage. (limited resources on my server)

Comment: @Dan: Buying more memory for a server is generally pretty cheap... and of course the database doesn't have to be on the same machine as your WCF service.

Comment: Thanks. Its actually on a rented VPS so I am trying to keep my monthly costs down by limiting RAM :-)

Comment: I managed to do this by setting up a SQL Express Database. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

When you store something in a **Dictionary** in your code, it persists only up to the duration of the code execution. In other words, your dictionary's lifetime is limited to your codes execution. To have longer storage, you have to use other mechanisms like **Session** or **Application**. But if you want the lifetime of your storage pass **application recycling**, then you should think of storing your data in database.

Comment: Thanks, I realise all of this,  and need to persist over server restarts ideally.